# Getting rid of the set builder notation in the expression $\{ f(x) \mid P(x) \} = \{ g(x)\mid Q(x) \}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, notation, predicate-logic, logic-translation

The [set-builer notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation) is used to have

$$\{ x \mid P(x) \} = \{ x \mid Q(x) \}$$

denote

$$\forall x\ \big(P(x) \Leftrightarrow Q(x) \big).$$

And some people write

$$\{ x \in U \mid P(x) \} = \{ x \in U \mid Q(x) \}$$

to denote

$$\forall x\ \big( x \in U \Rightarrow (P(x) \Leftrightarrow Q(x)) \big).$$

Now I want to translate the frequently used

$$\{ f(x) \mid P(x) \} = \{ g(x) \mid Q(x) \}$$

where the elements are not $x$, but sets constructed from them via $f$ and $g$. My try is

$$\forall y\ \big(\exists x\ \big(y=f(x)\land P(x)) \Leftrightarrow \exists x'\ \big(y=g(x')\land Q(x')\big) \big)$$

but I'm e.g. not sure about the existential quantifiert, or if I really need two.

I figure a necessary condition for having found the right way would be to try $f=g=\text{id}$ and see the formula reducing to the previous expression. However, I fail at this, because I don't know how to unpack it. I think I'd have to use $y=x$ and $y=x'$, but I don't know how I'd formally get this statement out of the long formula, so that I can use it?

> What is the right way to read $\{ f(x) \mid P(x) \} = \{ g(x) \mid Q(x) \}$ and how to show it reduces to $\forall x\ \big(P(x) \Leftrightarrow Q(x) \big)$ for $f=g=\text{id}$?

Comment: I didn't read everything, but hopefully this will help: $\{f(x)|P(x)\}$ should be read as $$\{y|\bigl(\exists x\in \text{dom}(f)\bigr)(f(x)=y)\land P(x)\}.$$ [Related](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to translate
>
> > $$\{ f(x) \mid P(x) \} = \{ g(x) \mid Q(x) \}\tag1$$
>
> My try is $$\forall y\ \big(\exists x\ \big(y=f(x)\land P(x)) \Leftrightarrow \exists x'\ \big(y=g(x')\land Q(x') \big) \big)\tag2$$

I obtained the same formalisation.

In Prenex form ([verification](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#%7E6y(%7E7a(Fay%7E1Pa)%7E4%7E7b(Gby%7E1Qb))%7E4%7E6y%7E6a%7E6b%7E7c%7E7d((Fay%7E1P(a))%7E2(Gby%7E1Q(b))%7E5Fcy%7E1Gdy%7E1P(c)%7E1Q(d)))): \begin{gather} ∀y\:∀a\:∀b\:∃c\:∃d\: \bigg(  \Big(y{=}f(a)∧P(a) \Big) ∨ \Big(y{=}g(b)∧Q(b) \Big) \\
 → y{=}f(c)∧y{=}g(d)∧P(c)∧Q(d)  \bigg).\tag3\end{gather}

> how to show it reduces to $\forall x\ \big(P(x) \Leftrightarrow Q(x) \big)$ for $f=g=\text{id}$?

Setting the $f$ and $g$ in $(3)$ as the identity function:
\begin{align}&∀y\:∀a\:∀b\:∃c\:∃d\: \bigg(  \Big(y=a∧P(a) \Big) ∨ \Big(y=b∧Q(b) \Big) \\
& → y=c∧y=d∧P(c)∧Q(d)  \bigg)\\
\equiv{}&∀y\: \bigg(  ∃a\:\Big(y=a∧P(a) \Big) ∨ ∃b\:\Big(y=b∧Q(b) \Big) \\
& → ∃c\:\Big(y=c∧P(c)\Big) ∧ ∃d\:\Big(y=d∧Q(d)\Big)\bigg)\\
\equiv{}&∀y\: \bigg(  P(y)  ∨ Q(y)  → P(y) ∧ Q(y)\bigg) \\
\equiv{}&∀y\:  \bigg( \big(\lnot P(y)  ∧  \lnot Q(y) \big)  ∨  \big( P(y)∧Q(y) \big) \bigg) \\
\equiv{}&∀y\:  \Big(  P(y) \leftrightarrow Q(y) \Big) \\
\equiv{}&∀x\:  \Big(  P(x) \leftrightarrow Q(x) \Big), \end{align}
where the second logical equivalence appeals to [Andreas's suggestion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/414978/21813) $$\exists x\,(y=x\land P(x)) \quad\equiv\quad \exists x\,(P(y)) \quad\equiv\quad P(y),$$ which when plugged into $(2)$ directly gives the same result.

Comment: Responding to a 10 year old thread, huh. I clearly forgot about this, but you'll get the green checkmark now.

Answer (score 1):

Your translation is correct.  To unpack the specialization to $f=g=\text{id}$, use the fact (of logic) that $\exists x\,(y=x\land P(x))$ is equivalent to $P(y)$.